# How to use Font Awesome 5 icons in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, font-awesome, laravel-6, font-awesome-5, fontawesome-4.4.0

I already installed Fontawesome in my **package.json**.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.11.2" ,
    //etc.
},
"dependencies": { "font-awesome": "^4.7.0" }
```

and import it to my **app.scss**

```
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

---

I tried `<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>` and `<i class="fas fa-edit"></i>` but it just shows like this below, someone knows how to do this correctly?

[image]

Comment: Have you used `npm` ?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya thats on my **package.json** i just `npm install`

Comment: And then you have installed `npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` Right? or not?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya yes Sir, well in fact **font-awesome** is already in my **node_modules** folder

Comment: You should provide `solid.scss` path in the `app.scss` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly import all `fontawesome-icons` in your `app.scss`

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

Second, and most important that **you missed is to copy the webfonts to your public folder**. In you `webpack.mis.js` append this below.

```
.copy('node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts', 'public/webfonts')
```

Answer (score 19):

### **Laravel 6 & 7 using Font Awesome 5 (The Right Way)**

Build your [webpack.mix.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/webpack.mix.js) configuration.

```js
mix.setPublicPath('public');
mix.setResourceRoot('../');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Install the latest free version of [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) via a package manager like [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free --save-dev
```

This dependency entry should now be in your [package.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json).

```json
// Font Awesome
"devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
```

In your main SCSS file, [/resources/sass/app.scss](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/sass/app.scss) import one or more styles.

```css
// Font Awesome
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

Compile your assets and produce a minified, production-ready build.

```
npm run production
```

Finally, reference your generated CSS file in your Blade template/layout.

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

### How to Install Font Awesome 5 with Laravel Mix 6 in Laravel 8 (The Right Way)

https://gist.github.com/karlhillx/89368bfa6a447307cbffc59f4e10b621

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me although by now the dependency shows `^5.12.1`, but that's a minor detail. The key for my installation to compile correctly was to run `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free --save`. That step is crucial.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you try this

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid -D
```

In the `resources/assets/js` folder, create a new file `fontawesome.js`

In the file you can import fontawesome and all icons.

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome';

import fas from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid';

fontawesome.library.add(fas);
```

In `resources/assets/js/app.js`

> require('./fontawesome');

Now run `npm run dev` to compile

Then you can use needed icon in your view

```
<i class="fas fa-*">
```

Comment: is it for all icons Sir or I need to import each icon? I want all icons

Comment: You need to import only the icons needed in your application. This method should work fine.

Comment: hmm. so I need to add icons whenever I have another one. thanks for your time Sir, but I want all icons so that if I have another one I dont need to specify.

Answer (score -1):

As you said you have already installed `font-awesome` package.

**app.scss**

Add this line:

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
```

And then

```
npm run watch
```

Comment: this time its shows none Sir, already inspect element. the font-awesome is present, but shows none.

Comment: @gecko You should add `fontawesome-free`  in the import path

Comment: it goes back again like the image above.

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

from the doc: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers

`npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

Then, in **app.js** I imported 'all.js':

`import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js';`

After `npm run watch` now I see the icons as `<i class="fas fa-search"></i>`